# Ignore trailing spaces when yanking a word in neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

So my issue when yanking a word (yw) is that it copies the trailing spaces as well:

Example:
Doing a yw on this:

```
‖Hello World
```

Results in copying `Hello`

But the same applies to:

```
‖LongVariableName                        = 'SomeValue';
```

Results in copying `LongVariableName`

Is there a way to make as such I copy without copying any space? (which for me makes sense when copying words)

Comment: `:help navigation` will blow your mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `yiw` to yank the 'inner word' text object (`yaw` would include an additional space). See `:help text-objects`.

A nice feature of text objects is that the cursor can be anywhere on the object (in this case the word) for it to work.

There are many text objects in vim:

- `is` means inner sentence
- `ip` means inner paragraph
- `i)` means inner parentheses

And many more!

Also the comment below by @DoktorOSwaldo points out that you can also use `ye` to yank from the current position until the end of the word without the space, `e` is the end of the current word, `w` is the start of the next word (this is not a text object, so repeating it on other words would require the cursor to be in the same position).

Comment: That works, so if really really want to only use the behaviour of yiw, I can remap yw to yiw.

Comment: You could, but I would **strongly recommend** not to remap a basic thing like `yw` to `yiw`! `yw` allows you to yank the second half of a word (from the cursor to the beginning of the next word) - you would lose that if you remapped. Also, there are all the other `dw`, `cw`, `gUw` etc. commands... you don't want to remap these to `diw`, `ciw`, `gUiw` ... And further, what about the `daw`, `caw`, `gUaw`.... I am guessing you're quite new to vim - it's a noob mistake to remap basic commands in vim like this... they are well thought out and it pays to learn the basics as they were intended.

Comment: note: you can also use `ye` to yank from the current position until the end of the word without the space, `e` is the end of the current word, `w` is the start of the next word.